# Passing additional information per input box using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I'm asking this question since I'm simply not clear on where to research further - I have experience primarily with Python, while my HTML and Javascript knowledge are on an as-needed basis. I simply haven't been able to figure out the most elegant and standard way to do this, and which component (the HTML itself, a Javascript component, Django) should be responsible for doing what I want.

I am trying to create a form for input of linguistic data with a Django app. Important for what I'm doing here is that each datum has associated tags. Also, most linguistic data is paradigmatic, so I want to be able to have users input an entire paradigm at a time (rather than one single datum at a time, which can be done already using the Django admin interface). I also, ultimately, want to have the paradigmatic input be dynamic in the future, so that I do not have to hardcode things.

For example, I would like have a form that looks like the following:
[image: Pronoun Input Form]

On submit, I would like the page to send something like this to the server:

```
'I', tags:'singular, 1st'
'we', tags:'plural, 1st'
ˈYou',tags:'singular, 2nd,masculine'
 ...
```

I simply don't know what the best way is to embed this extra data into the website so that it gets submitted when the page gets submitted. Ideally, the input boxes could somehow 'inherit' the tags based on their position in the columns and rows rather than each input box needing to be have that information added individually.

The only idea I've had so far is to embed the tag information into the names of the input boxes so that the string passed on a get command would be something like '?singular_1st=I&plural_1st=we&singular_2nd_masculine=You' and I would just have to process the strings on the Django backend. I could also use javascript to assign the names of each of the textboxes on pageload somehow, though I'm not sure how to figure out which textbox is located where relative to the headers of the table.

What is the best way to do this? Can I somehow pass more structured data on submitting the page, rather than having to reparse everything on the backend? I've read something about passing JSON to the server, but I'm not sure how exactly to do this. Similarly, there's a data attribute in HTML 5, but I'm not sure how (or if) that gets passed to the server on submitting a page. I'm not asking for anyone to do my coding for me, but simply a suggestion about how best to do this and further resources or tutorials showing similar projects.

Comment: are you looking to then save and re-display this data? I would simply have the form submit, then in the backend format the `I, tags...` bit.

Comment: I would like to save the data to the server. It doesn't necessarily have to be redisplayed.

I'm not really sure how to get the form to submit the tag data in the first place (as opposed to just the text data from the input boxes)- that's what my question is really.